# SQL Server 2008 / Reporting Services query

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services

I need some help with my recursive query to get a direct count (all members(children) directly) and total count (all team members) for my SSRS report.

Here is my current query and the result set.

```
WITH AgentHierarchy([Name], AId, UId, HLevel, ContractDate) 
AS 
(SELECT  
     FirstName + ' ' + LastName  AS Name, AId, UId, 
     0 AS HLevel, ContractDate                       
 FROM    tbl_Asso 
 WHERE  (AId ='A049')

 UNION ALL

 SELECT      
     e.FirstName + ' ' + e.LastName AS Name,
 e.AId, e.UId, 
     eh.HLevel + 1 AS HLevel, e.ContractDate
 FROM        
     tbl_Asso AS e 
 INNER JOIN 
     AgentHierarchy AS eh ON eh.AId = e.UId)
SELECT   
    AId, Name,
(select u.FirstName + ' ' + u.LastName  
     from tbl_Asso u 
     where u.AId = d.UId) as Upline,
    UId, 
    HLevel,  
    ContractDate,
    (Select count(*)  
     from tbl_Asso as dc 
     where dc.UId = d.AId) As DirectCount
FROM    
    AgentHierarchy AS d
ORDER BY 
    HierarchyLevel
```

the current result set

```
AId    Name         Upline       UId  HLevel ContractDate  DirectCount
-----------------------------------------------------------------------    
A049  King Bori     Cindy Hoss    A001  0   8/29/2012   5
A052  Kac Marque    King Bori     A049  1   11/6/2012   0
A050  Joseph Moto   King Bori     A049  1   10/9/2012   1
A059  Nancy Ante    King Bori     A049  1   3/27/2013   1
A053  Kathy May     King Bori     A049  1   11/15/2012  2
A057  Robert Murphy King Bori     A049  1   2/12/2013   1
A051  Andy Jane     Joseph Moto   A050  2   2/14/2013   0
A060  Arian Colle   Nancy Ante    A059  2   3/26/2013   0
A058  Phil Hunk     Robert Murphy A057  2   3/21/2013   0
A055  Rea Wane      Kathy May     A053  2   2/20/2013   1
A054  Gabby Orez    Kathy May     A053  2   12/7/2012   0
A056  Steve Wells   Rea Wane      A055  3   3/25/2013   0
```

I Need  to change the above query to get the  Direct count (all Members(children) directly)  and TotalTeam count based on the contract date

E.g for e.g contract date between 03/01/2013 and 03/31/2013. I need to get the following result set.

I need to incorporate the parameter for contractDate (so that they can get the range or if it is null then they get all the records and the counts.

e.g (ContractDate between @Begindate and @Enddate) or ((@Begindate is null) and (@enddate is null))

```
AId    Name         Upline       UId  HLevel ContractDate  DirectCount  TotalTeam
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------  
A049  King Bori     Cindy Hoss    A001  0   8/29/2012   1     4 
A052  Kac Marque    King Bori     A049  1   11/6/2012   0     0
A050  Joseph Moto   King Bori     A049  1   10/9/2012   0     0
A059  Nancy Ante    King Bori     A049  1   3/27/2013   1     1
A053  Kathy May     King Bori     A049  1   11/15/2012  0     0
A057  Robert Murphy King Bori     A049  1   2/12/2013   1     1
A051  Andy Jane     Joseph Moto   A050  2   2/14/2013   0     0
A060  Arian Colle   Nancy Ante    A059  2   3/26/2013   0     0
A058  Phil Hunk     Robert Murphy A057  2   3/21/2013   0     0
A055  Rea Wane      Kathy May     A053  2   2/20/2013   1     1
A054  Gabby Orez    Kathy May     A053  2   12/7/2012   0     0
A056  Steve Wells   Rea Wane      A055  3   3/25/2013   0     0
```

Thanks In advance.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain but you are doing an explicit listing of a single person in your recursive CTE, this will limit scope to just that person and their parents ONLY.  Unless you are doing recursion on a starting set of millions of records it should be able to handle a predicate at the bottom of the regular expression and not in the recursive CTE by itself.  Provided you are handling proper max recursion level.  For your contract date just leave that table out till the bottom where you link the recursion.  Unless you need to get their levels first.  In that case I would get that data in a first cte, then list a second one doing recurion on that.

Here is a simple example I do that includes combined sales, basically I form the recursion and am not id specific, I find max recursion(you can leave that part out if you want) to find the lowest leaf level, then I perform end predicates needed.  I hope this helps.  A lot of times I see people listing predicates in their recursive CTE that will limit their scope, keep in mind recursion is in essence limiting a layer over top itself n times.  You can get data you need before and after that point but doing predicates in there will limit where that scope leads to.

```
Declare @table table ( PersonId int identity, PersonName varchar(512), Account int, ParentId int, Orders int);

insert into @Table values ('Brett', 1, NULL, 1000),('John', 1, 1, 100),('James', 1, 1, 200),('Beth', 1, 2, 300),('John2', 2, 4, 400);

select 
    PersonID
,   PersonName
,   Account
,   ParentID
from @Table

; with recursion as 
    (
    select 
        t1.PersonID
    ,   t1.PersonName
    ,   t1.Account
    --, t1.ParentID
    ,   cast(isnull(t2.PersonName, '')
            + Case when t2.PersonName is not null then '\' + t1.PersonName else t1.PersonName end
            as varchar(255)) as fullheirarchy
    ,   1 as pos
    ,   cast(t1.orders + 
            isnull(t2.orders,0) -- if the parent has no orders than zero
            as int) as Orders
    from @Table t1
        left join @Table t2 on t1.ParentId = t2.PersonId
    union all
    select 
        t.PersonID
    ,   t.PersonName
    ,   t.Account
    --, t.ParentID
    ,   cast(r.fullheirarchy + '\' + t.PersonName as varchar(255))
    ,   pos + 1  -- increases
    ,   r.orders + t.orders
    from @Table t
        join recursion r on t.ParentId = r.PersonId
    )
, b as 
    (
    select *, max(pos) over(partition by PersonID) as maxrec  -- I find the maximum occurrence of position by person
    from recursion
    )
select *
from b
where pos = maxrec  -- finds the furthest down tree
-- and Account = 2  -- I could find just someone from a different department
```